# filter query and jmespath contains for something in array

Tags: azure

I have an az cli command that returns two results. I want it to return the one correct result.

az ad sp list --all --filter "servicePrincipalType eq 'ManagedIdentity'" --query "[?displayName=='runner'].{displayName:displayName,id:id}" --output tsv

At the top of each of the two results I see:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "addIns": [],
    "alternativeNames": [
      "isExplicit=True",
      "/subscriptions/123456-dc65-5e45-9bcc-7fdf8d187d34/resourcegroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/runner"
```

I want the query to filter down to the alternativeNames that has my-rg in it.

I tried:

```
az ad sp list --all --filter "servicePrincipalType eq 'ManagedIdentity'" --query "[?displayName=='runner']|[?contains(AlternativeNames[1],'my-rg')].{displayName:displayName,id:id}" --output tsv
```

That did not work because I think I am using it wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently casing is important. I changed to use alternativeNames[1] and it worked!